# How to determine whether a set is a vector space or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently learning Vector Spaces and although I understand the definition of what a vector space is, I can't seem to be able to find the correct answers when doing some questions. I would even say that I'm getting some answers right by pure luck and that's defeats the purpose of mathematics.

My problem is that I don't know the correct approach to solve these questions.

Here are a few questions which I'm trying to do but I'm not sure how to arrive to my answers:

In the questions below, I should determine whether each of the sets given is a vector space or not:

1. $V = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x-y+2z = 3\}$
2. $V = \{p\in P_{4}[x] : p(0) + p(1) = 0\}$
3. $V = \{A\in M_{3*3} : A = A^{t}\}$
4. $V = \{A\in M_{3*3} : AA^{t} = -I\}$

Now, all of the answers are yes except for number $4$, is a vector space.
I got $1$ wrong and $4$ wrong. I got numbers $2$ and $3$ right but I'm not sure if my way of finding the answer is right. I normally just use the definition of a Vector Space but it doesn't work all the time.

Edit: I'm not simply looking for the final answer( I already have them) but I'm more interested in understanding how to approach such questions to reach the final answer.

Edit 2:
The answers given in the memo are as follows:

```
1. Vector Space
2. Vector Space
3. Vector Space
4. Not a  Vector Space
```

Could anyone please explain how to get the answer in detail and if there is a trick to quickly find the answers?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes for 2 and 3, no for 1 and 4.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing in trying to verify if each cases is following or not the axioms of a vector space?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx I'm just trying to determine whether each of the set given is a Vector Space or not, but I'm concerned on how to approach the questions to reach the final solution.

Comment: In several comments you say something like "the answer says 1 is a vector space". It's not, as several people have pointed out. Can you provide a source for "the answer" so we can study it?

Comment: @EthanBolker The answers  were provided in the memo for the questions and they go as follows:
1. Vector Space
2. Vector Space
3. Vector Space
4. Not a  Vector Space

Comment: Whoever wrote that memo made a mistake. You will be doing fellow students a favor If you can point that out politely and have it corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to see whether the sets are subspaces of the given vector spaces.

The first necessary condition to check is whether the zero vector belongs to the set: if not, we're done because the set is not a subspace.
Note that this is not sufficient, so if the zero vector is in the set we need to do other checks.

The zero vector doesn't belong to the set in number 1, nor in the set of number 4.

For numbers 2 and 3, it's easier if you recall that the null space of a linear map is a subspace; for 2 consider
$$
f\colon P_4[x]\to \mathbb{R},\qquad f(p)=p(0)+p(1)
$$

For 3 consider
$$
g\colon M_{3*3}\to M_{3*3},\qquad g(A)=A-A^t
$$

Are these maps linear?

Comment: Could you please explain number 1 in more detail. I tried to solve number 1 and I found out that it's not a vector space. However the answer says it's a vector space. Could you please explain in more details Number 1?

Comment: 1) is not a V.S. since (0,0,0) is not there.

Comment: @Sabir The answer is wrong: $(0,0,0)$ doesn't belong to $V$. The set *may* be made into a vector space, but under *different* operations than the standard ones on triples. Are you sure you reported the exercise correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Note that all sets are subsets of vector spaces. Thus you have to check whether they are subspaces:

- Is the zero element of the underlying vector space also in the subset?
- Take two arbitrary elements from the subset. Is their sum also in the subset?
- Take an element $x$ of the subset and a number $\lambda$ of the underlying field (in most cases either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). Is $\lambda x$ also in the subset?

Only if the answer to all of the above questions is "yes" the subset is a vector space.

Example: In (1) the zero vector $(0,0,0)$ is no element of $V$ because $0-0+30\neq 0$. Thus in (1) $V$ is no vector space because the answer to the first question is "no".

Comment: Could you please explain number 1 in more detail. I tried to solve number 1 and I found out that it's not a vector space. However the answer says it's a vector space. Could you please explain in more details Number 1?

Comment: Done ;-) Note that $(0,0,0)\notin V$ in (1)...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes more sense now.